# connect to aws from shared-ip on cpanel

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have installed neo4j on aws and its running fine .I have set tcp 7474 to my ip and ssh is working fine . I can connect to aws from my mamp-PHP as I have added my-ip into security group .

If set I TCP/IP from Anywhere=0.0.0.0/0 ,I am unable to access it. HOw can I connect from shared-ip(cpanel-PHP) ?

I really appreciate any help.I am struggling with this from last 3 days.

```
<?php

$data2 ='CREATE (Person:Person {name:”test”}) RETURN Person';
$data2 = array("query" =>$data2);
$data_string = json_encode($data2);


$ch = curl_init('http://aws_ip:7474/db/data/cypher');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
);


$result = curl_exec($ch);

echo $result;

?>
```

Comment: Connect to AWS is pretty vague; what are you trying to do exactly.  Connect to RDS, SSH into another EC2 instance, etc?

Comment: I am trying to make a rest call I have updated the Q with code.But this php is not inserting the data.But I can execute the same php from mamp/wamp server.

Comment: I see.  You're certain that you have set the right secgroup on the instance you launched, and that this security group grants ingress on 7474?

Comment: You're not behind a load balancer?

Comment: I dont have any load balancer and also if I keep tcp/ip from anywhere, its still not working.Also tried from 2 different cpanel which have different shared-ip.Do I need to add any other setting ?

Comment: Could be an egress filter on your cpanel box.  Can you SSH into your cpanel box at all? Try doing that and then telnetting to 7474

Comment: I dont have ssh access on cpanel

Comment: But I could connect to the aws.ip from local without ssh as tcp/ip has my ip. or should I install php on aws linux ami ?? I really appreciate you looking into it.Thanks Saeven

Comment: If it works local to AWS, but doesn't work CPanel to AWS, you're probably looking at a firewall on your CPanel machine.  Install CFS and open up the port.  Get your admin to help if you don't have access.  OR, better, ditch cPanel and run a t1.micro ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72368/discussion-between-jason-and-saeven).

Comment: Yeah. I would like to ditch cpanel.How can I get php on t1 micro?
Also thanks for all the help
Should I install php or both php/mysql and apache .Also do I need apache to run php? And also whats the diff between php and phpmyadmin(or is there any??)
Is this good ? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wNr7YqjjzOY
Please reply . I am struggling from 3 days but no answer

Comment: @Saeven Please can you let me know how to proceed.It would be of great help please.